# Problemas com a leitura do struct na função

Tags: c

Faz vários dias que estou tentando entender pq esse erro ocorre, mas não encontrei em lugar nenhum. É o seguinte, eu declarei um vetor da struct dados e passei esse vetor para a função que o recebe com um parâmetro tipo ponteiro, porém, quando eu vou ler os dados com o operador especial -> dá o seguinte erro, "invalid type argument of '->', alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Relacionar o item

->'

```
# include stdio.h

typedef struct {
    char avenida[70];
    char bairro[70];
    int numero;
    char complemento[40];
    char cidade[30];
    char uf[2];
    long int cep;

} Endereco;


typedef struct {
    char nome[50];
    int telefone[3];
    Endereco endereco;

} Dados;

Dados dados[5];

void ler_dados(Dados *dados, int tamanho);

int main() {

    int count;

    ler_dados(dados, 5);

    return 0;

}

void  ler_dados(Dados *dados, int tamanho) {
    int count;

    for(count=0; count<tamanho; count++) {
        printf("Usuário %d\n", count+1);

        gets(&dados[count]->avenida);
        gets(&dados[count]->bairro);
        scanf("%d", &dados[count]->bairro);
        gets(&dados[count]->complemento);
        gets(&dados[count]->cidade);
        scanf("%s" &dados[count]->uf);
        scanf("%ld", &dados[count]->cep);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O operador -> espera que o elemento da esquerda seja um ponteiro.

Ao escrever:

```
&dados[count]->avenida
```

Você está tentando pegar o atributo avenida de `dados[count]`, que é do tipo Dados, não ponteiro de Dados.

Uma alternativa é utilizar o operador `.`:

```
&dados[count].avenida
```

Ou colocar paranteses para definir a ordem:

```
&(&dados[count]).avenida
```

Em seguida provavelmente você vai ter outro erro por estar tentando ler avenida do tipo Dados que não têm esse atributo, acho que no final, uma linha sua deve ficar algo como:

```
gets(dados[count].endereco.avenida);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu código possui muitos erros de sintaxe. primeiramente para importar o `stdio.h`, deve ter os caracteres `<` e `>` para definir a biblioteca que esta importando: **`include <stdio.h>`**.

A sua função `ler_dados` tem um parâmetro do tipo `Dados` e a estrutura `Dados` possui apenas os campos `nome`, `telefone` e `endereco`, Assim não é possível fazer a leitura do jeito que esta sendo feita.

A função `gets` também não é recomendada para fazer a leitura do texto, para isso se usa o `scanf` com o parametro `"%[^\n]"` ou a função `fgets`.

Em *C* os ponteiros também são vetores, e quando se tenta acessar uma posição de um ponteiro, ela deixa de ser um ponteiro, e quando se usa o `&` em uma estrutura com o atributo, o `&` agira no ultimo item da linha ex:

```
&dados[0]; // retorna o endereço de memória de dados[0]
&dados[0].nome // retorna o endereço de memória de nome dentro de dados
(&dados[0])->nome // retorna o endereço de memória de dados[0] e pega o nome
```

Assim o jeito q seu código está estruturado está errado.

**Jeito errado:**

```
gets(&dados[count]->avenida);
gets(&dados[count]->bairro);
scanf("%d", &dados[count]->bairro);
gets(&dados[count]->complemento);
gets(&dados[count]->cidade);
scanf("%s", &dados[count]->uf);
scanf("%ld", &dados[count]->cep);
```

E o jeito certo de fazer a estruturação seria:

**Jeito certo:**

```
void  ler_dados(Dados *dados, int tamanho) {
    int count;

    for(count=0; count<tamanho; count++) {
        printf("Usuário %d\n", count+1);

        scanf("%[^\n]",dados[count].endereco.avenida);
        scanf("%[^\n]",dados[count].endereco.bairro);
        scanf("%[^\n]",dados[count].endereco.complemento);
        scanf("%[^\n]",dados[count].endereco.cidade);
        scanf("%s", dados[count].endereco.uf);
        scanf("%ld", &dados[count].endereco.cep); # aqui é pego o endereço de memória da variável cep dentro de endereco
    }
}
```